# Any ideas on making this VBScript function faster?

Tags: vbscript

I need to call this function a few times in different parts of my main script. It simply looks to see if the software is installed (it is given the software name as an argument).

This is just a snippet of the code, which is this function. The remote aspect of it works fine.

```
'*************************************************************************
' This Subroutine checks if software is installed on system
'*************************************************************************
Sub CheckInstalledSoftware(item)
   ' This sub is VERY slow
   blnCondition = False 'Simple check to see if software was found
   WScript.Echo("Check if " & item & " is installed.")
   WScript.Echo("------------------------------------")
   Set colSoftware = objWMISrvc.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Product WHERE Name = '" & item & "'")
   For Each objSoftware in colSoftware
                If (objSoftware.InstallState = 5) Then
                   WScript.Echo(item & " is installed" & vbCrLf)
                   blnCondition = True
                End  If
   Next
   If blnCondition <> True Then
      WScript.Echo(item & " is not installed" & vbCrLf)
   End If


End Sub
```

Comment: How long does it currently take to run, and which line of code is consuming most of the time?

Comment: It takes about 10-25 seconds to run (which adds up when calling it a lot). I'm not sure which part is taking so long. I have the timer function running on my whole script, but it slows to a crawl when it hits this function.

Comment: It's probably the `objWMISrvc.ExecQuery`.  I'm not sure there's much you can do about that, other than to limit the number of times you call it and cache the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to make this any faster.  The Win32_Product class has a massive overhead.  Your only option is to find a method that does not require using this particular WMI class.  If you have additional code, you could execute this portion asynchronously while doing something else.  You'll notice the same poor performance if you open the Add and Remove Programs dialog as well.